# LaTeX-Font in Word 2016

Tags: fonts, msword, word-to-latex

How to use Latex font in Word?

I downloaded several OpenTypes (XITS, Computer Modern, etc.).

None of the beauty can compare with him:

$\ddot{x}+\alpha \cdot \dot{x}-\nabla^2f(x)-\nabla f(x)=0$

Comment: `LaTeX fonts` are especially designed for `LaTeX`, not sure whether it supports other platforms like `MS-Word`

Comment: @MadyYuvi Or maybe there are some similar ones?

Comment: most modern opentype version of computer modern math is https://ctan.org/pkg/newcomputermodern  specifically  NewCMMath-Book.otf http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/newcomputermodern/otf/NewCMMath-Book.otf although you will have it already in texlive or miktex.

Comment: @MadyYuvi any font that you can use in lualatex or xelatex with `unicode-math` you can use in Word (`unicode-math` package uses the format _defined_ by Microsoft for use in Word)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you. I'm used to Word and now I need a good font there.

Comment: what is a good math font though depends on what font you are using for text. Word's Cambria Math is a good match for Cambria, NewCMMath less so, unless you also plan to use NewCM for text

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In general, in the future I want to type in Overleaf. Using Word now is a necessary necessity ))).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the update, I'll update myself....

Comment: This isn't clearly on topic here but [Word showing the latex-linear and professional display of the supplied equation using New CM Math](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sM8NM.png)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle hmmm...what is this ??? how to do it?

Comment: @dtn don't ask me I think I have only ever written one document in word. I just installed the font in windows, then copied the text you posted into a word math zone with linear (latex) option set then did the same again and select the professional option so it displayed

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'll try

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I got something like this. https://ibb.co/RCt0bq0 Beautiful, but for some reason the formulas transformed "crooked". Something had to bring hands. In PowerPoint, the font did not connect at all (there is a list, but the font does not change).

Comment: sorry this is the wrong forum to get help on Word and I'm certainly the wrong person to ask, I never use it at all.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle everything is ok, the most important thing is that now the font changes at least in the Word. Anyway, your advice helped. If it's not difficult, you can arrange it in the form of a full-fledged answer and show the result.

Comment: @dtn really I don't see how this is on topic here, I'm not sure what else I can say that isn't in the above comment, I have told you everything I know,